# How to make movement of select options circular?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider the following select element. Try to move navigate through the options using arrow keys. You see when you reach the bottom you can't move to top if you press down once more. And same for the top.

```html
<select>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
```

I want to have this feature with select. But the issue is that I am unable to find out anyway get the option which is temporarily selected while navigating.

One thing I found out is to change the `selectedIndex` of the element but this also doesn't work because it doesn't change the current hovered/active option of select rather it changes actual value of select.

I have a restriction that I have to use only simple select element of html.

I will be thankful if you are able to help me out.

Comment: Have you tried: `document.querySelector('select').value`?

Comment: @NNL993 Yes but it is also not working.

Comment: Very suspicious, I tried my solution right now, and it's working fine.(Using your HTML example)

Comment: @NNL993 Maybe I am missing something in my way. Please add an answer if you think its working fine.

Comment: Answer added, also, I add one more solution if `el.value` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let $1 = document.querySelector('#s1')
let $2 = document.querySelector('#s2')
console.log('S1 VALUE:', $1.value, '\nS2 VALUE:', $2.value)
```

```html
<!-- DEFAULT -->

<select id="s1">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select><br>

<!-- PRE-SELECTED -->

<select id="s2">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option selected value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
```

There is a screenshot of my result:

[image]

If that solution doesn't work, you can try this:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('select').selectedOptions[0].value)
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
```

In that snippet I used: [`selectedOptions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions), in options array I choose first object because in `<select>` element we can choose only single option, so then I get itself value.